# C gl-matrix, how to create vectors and matrices?

Tags: c, matrix, vector

It's code from vec3.c in gl-matrix.

```
vec3_t vec3_create(vec3_t vec) {
vec3_t dest = calloc(sizeof(double_t), 3);

if (vec) {
    dest[0] = vec[0];
    dest[1] = vec[1];
    dest[2] = vec[2];
} else {
    dest[0] = dest[1] = dest[2] = 0;
}

return dest;
}
```

How can I crate new vector using that function?
How to create vector with different values?
I was trying to set double values to array like this:

```
vec3_t vec;
vec3_t vec3_create(vec);
vec[0] = 1.0;
vec[1] = 0.0;
vec[2] = 0.0;
```

But I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS. Have the same problem with matrices.

Code in mat4.c in gl-matrix.

```
mat4_t mat4_create(mat4_t mat) {
mat4_t dest = calloc(sizeof(double), 16);

if (mat) {
    dest[0] = mat[0];
    dest[1] = mat[1];
    dest[2] = mat[2];
    dest[3] = mat[3];
    dest[4] = mat[4];
    dest[5] = mat[5];
    dest[6] = mat[6];
    dest[7] = mat[7];
    dest[8] = mat[8];
    dest[9] = mat[9];
    dest[10] = mat[10];
    dest[11] = mat[11];
    dest[12] = mat[12];
    dest[13] = mat[13];
    dest[14] = mat[14];
    dest[15] = mat[15];
}

return dest;
}
```

EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

```
mat4_t transform_mat;
mat4_create(transform_mat);
```

Comment: You don't check if `calloc` returns null, which it can do if it runs out of memory.

Comment: Does my answer make sense to you? Please check, I am using a tablet. Can't verify.

Comment: @Elyasin Yes vectors are working perfect right now. Only those matrices... Have no idea how use them now. But I'll check documention. Thanks

Comment: I update the answer. I recommend doing the first C course (CLA) of the C++ institute. I believe you need to learn some basics. I'm convinced this will be very helpful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`vec3_t` is a pointer to a double as defined in the header

```
typedef double *vec3_t;
```

From the header you find also some documentation, which will tell you how to use it:

```
/*
 * vec3_t - 3 Dimensional Vector
 */

/*
 * vec3_create
 * Creates a new instance of a vec3_t
 *
 * Params:
 * vec - Optional, vec3_t containing values to initialize with. If NULL, the 
 * vector will be initialized with zeroes.
 *
 * Returns:
 * New vec3
 */
vec3_t vec3_create(vec3_t vec);
```

So you would might want to do something like this:

```
vec3_t vec = vec3_create(NULL); // initially a vector with 0s
vec[0] = 1.0;                   // set the first element to 1.0
```

In regard to the matrix:

```
mat4_t transform_mat = mat4_create(NULL);
```

This will allocate memory and `transform_mat` will point to its address. You need to initialize the values yourself, as they are not initialized to 0s by default (as it is done with vec3_t).